# Difference between a 'regular' pivot table and an olap-type pivot table

Tags: excel, ssas, olap, cube

In Excel, if you create a pivot table in the application it looks something like this:

[image]

Where the fields are all 'flattened' or at the top level. However, if you author something in SSAS or another utility you can create an OLAP structure where the fields are more structured into Dimensions (a separate collapsible folder/item), Measures (separate collapsible folder/item), KPIs (a separate collapsible folder/item), and potentially multi-level hierarchies (a nested item). For example:

[image]

Is there any way to author that type of structure directly in Excel? Or do you need to use something like Visual Studio/BIDS in order to do so? Asa corollary, is it possible to build an entirely 'flat' OLAP structure, so that all fields are at the same top level in Excel? This is sometimes a bit simpler to use for a business user that is used to a 'normal' pivot table.

Answer (score 1):

The first picture in your post is the standard PivotTable design page, when we try to create Pivot Table in excel.  We could not arrange the measures or dimensions in Excel directly to have the structure as in your second picture.

Within my experience, we need to built the analysis project in VS / SSDT to make a pivot table as in the second picture. You could download the extension in Visual studio extensions-online, named as Analysis Project extension .

> Asa corollary, is it possible to build an entirely 'flat' OLAP
> structure, so that all fields are at the same top level in Excel?

No. The measure and dimension will be arranged under different folders automatically.